# How can I print out a large table of symbols from MATLAB to form a cross-stitch chart?

Tags: matlab

[On this website](http://www.picturecraftwork.com), one can create stitch charts from images. I'm trying to do this in MATLAB. I have implemented everything using the Image Processing Toolbox (Reducing of number of the colors, mapping to the color space of available yarn colors). I'm done with all of this, the only thing I still need to do is to create an output similar to these files from MATLAB, which basically show which yarn to use for each raster point of the stitch chart:

[BW](http://www.picturecraftwork.com/gallery/generic/554.pattern-bw.pdf)

[Color](http://www.picturecraftwork.com/gallery/generic/554.pattern-fc.pdf)

My question is how to print a table with a lot of very small fields with the color and/or symbol inside.
It should look somehow like in these PDF files. How can I print out a table like this? Directly from MATLAB? Can I create a PDF file like this in MATLAB? Should I export it to Excel somehow?

Answer (score 0):

For the "color" PDF you linked, this looks just like a pixelated image. Why don't you save each "field" as one pixel, for example in a TIF file using `imwrite(I, 'filename')`? You could then print this TIF into a PDF using an appropriate scaling factor to make the pixels large enough.

For the "BW" PDF which basically contains a large table of symbols, it would probably be easiest to go through HTML or [RTF file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) to get the table of symbols, and then use some html2pdf or rtf2pdf converter...